# Filter out data in a large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter out some years in my very large dataframe.
This is a very short and easy version of my data:

```
Year  Value  Symbol
2001  0.1      ABC
2002  0.1      ABC
2003  0.2      ABC
2002  0.4      ZZZ
2003  0.8      ZZZ
2000  0.9      ASD
2001  0.1      ASD
2002  0.3      ASD
2003  0.2      ASD
```

As you can see different symbols have different starting year in my dataset. For example symbol ASD has its first value in 2000 while symbol ZZZ only in 2002. I in this specific I would like only to preserve the data for years where all symbols have their value.  The result should look like this:

```
Year  Value  Symbol  
2002  0.1      ABC
2003  0.2      ABC
2002  0.4      ZZZ
2003  0.8      ZZZ
2002  0.3      ASD
2003  0.2      ASD
```

The problem with my large dataframe is that I have a lot of dates and I dont know the starting date for every symbol(and I have a lot of symbols). So I should first find the starting date for each symbol(or the symbol with the latter starting date) and after that delete all the unnecessary data. Is there a way of efficiently doing this in pandas/python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='Year', columns='Symbol', values='Value')
        .dropna()
        .unstack()
        .reset_index(name='Value')

print (df)
  Symbol  Year  Value
0    ABC  2002    0.1
1    ABC  2003    0.2
2    ASD  2002    0.3
3    ASD  2003    0.2
4    ZZZ  2002    0.4
5    ZZZ  2003    0.8
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to share your current code to get more informative performance suggestions; here is one straightforward approach:
Find out how many unique symbols there are, and keep only the years that have exactly that many unique symbols.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''Year  Value  Symbol
2001  0.1      ABC
2002  0.1      ABC
2003  0.2      ABC
2002  0.4      ZZZ
2003  0.8      ZZZ
2000  0.9      ASD
2001  0.1      ASD
2002  0.3      ASD
2003  0.2      ASD'''), sep=r' +')

unique_symbol_count = df.Symbol.value_counts().keys().shape[0]
good_years_df = df.groupby('Year').filter(lambda gp: gp.Symbol.value_counts().shape[0] == unique_symbol_count)

#    Year  Value Symbol
# 1  2002    0.1    ABC
# 2  2003    0.2    ABC
# 3  2002    0.4    ZZZ
# 4  2003    0.8    ZZZ
# 7  2002    0.3    ASD
# 8  2003    0.2    ASD
```